# Inequality releating squared absolute value of an integral to the integral of the squared absolute values of the integrand

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Is this inequality $\left| \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \ dt \right|^2 \leq \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)|^2 \ dx$ true for $x\in [0,1]$. In case it is how to prove it?

If there is no square in both sides it is easy since it will be the triangle inequality $\left| \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \ dt \right| \leq \int_{0}^{x} |f(t)| \ dx$. But if I try to rise the both sides of this inequality on a power of two I can't get the desired result.

Comment: It cannot be true for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, otherwise it would lead to $$L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)\subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^+).$$

Comment: And $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2/3}}$ belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ but not to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, then we can get 
\begin{align}
\Bigl|\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt\Bigr|^{2}\leq \left(\int_{0}^{x} 1^{2}dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^{2}dt\right)=x\left(\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^{2}dt\right)
\end{align}
So for $x\in [0,1]$, your inequality is true.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention a counterexample for $x > 1$ (e.g. $f \equiv 1$)

Comment: @AhmedHussein Thanks for a comment.

Comment: @See-WooLee Left of the inequality we have the absolute value of the inner product $|\langle 1|f(t) \rangle|^2$, while the integrals to the right of the inequality are the Lebesgue $L_p$-norms $||1||_L^2$ and $||f(t)||_L^2$ right?

Comment: @Pekov Yes, for $p=2$.

Comment: Sorry but why is this Cauchy-Schwarz? I thought the LHS should be $\|f 1\|^2 = \int_0^x |f|^2dt$?