# Compute the Resolvent of derivative with domain $H^1(0,\pi)$ where $f(0)=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

So this is a question from Teschl G. - Mathematical methods in quantum mechanics- Problem 2.19 \

Compute the resolvent of $$Af=f' \enspace D(A)=\{f\in H^1[0,1] \enspace | \enspace f(0)=0\}$$

and show that unbounded operators can have empty spectrum. Where
$$D(A)\subseteq L^2[a,b] \enspace \text{and} \enspace Ran(A)\subseteq L^2[a,b]$$

I tried to calculate directly or to imitate the example in the book but they all just stayed as a restatement of definitions.Like if this then this then this and nothing.  
So thank you for your answers

Comment: Are you assuming the range of $A$ to lie in $L^2[0,1]$ or in $H^1[0,1]$?

Comment: i think domain of A lies in $L^2$ so image also lies in there (probably)  because $L^2[a,b]\supseteq AC \supseteq H^1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you are considering $\frac{d}{dx} : \mathcal{D}(\frac{d}{dx})\subset L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,1]$, where $\mathcal{D}(\frac{d}{dx})$ consists of all functions $f\in H^1[0,1]$ that vanish at $0$. Given $g\in L^2[0,1]$, the resolvent equation is
$$
                     \left(\frac{d}{dx}-\lambda I\right)f=g,\;\;\; f\in H^1[0,1], f(0)=0,  \lambda\in\mathbb{C}. \\
                      \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-\lambda x}f)=e^{-\lambda x}g \\ 
                     \int_0^x \frac{d}{dx'}(e^{-\lambda x'}f(x'))dx'=\int_0^x e^{-\lambda x'}g(x')dx' \\
             e^{-\lambda x}f(x) = \int_0^x e^{-\lambda x'}g(x')dx' \\
                   f(x) = e^{\lambda x}\int_0^x e^{-\lambda x'}g(x')dx'.
$$
So, the resolvent $R(\lambda)=(\frac{d}{dx}-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is defined for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and is given by
$$
      R(\lambda)g = \int_0^x e^{\lambda(x-x')}g(x')dx'.
$$
It's not hard to verify that $R(\lambda) : L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ is a bounded operator for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. That means $\frac{d}{dx}$ has no spectrum.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i really appreciate

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç : You're welcome. This is how I learned the subject, and I know how important these types of examples are. By the way, you can +1 the answer if you're so inclined, in addition to selecting it as the answer as you have done. I say this because I noticed you're a new user of the site. BTW I don't know why someone down-voted your question, but I just up-voted to cancel theirs. This is an important example.

Comment: Thanks i need 15 reputation in order to upvote i tried but :D.I answered some basic analysis question but i got in argument with someone probably he(she) did it.(I don't know why :D)

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç : Most of us around here do a good job of being polite. I've had a couple of run-ins with people around here, too, and knew I shouldn't. Oh, well. :)

Comment: So i tried to show that indeed $R(\lambda)$ is bounded.Could you check :).Let $g\in L^2[0,1]$ with norm 1 with inner product defined on $L^2$ $$\int_{0}^{1}|\int_{0}^{x}e^{\lambda(x-x')}g(x')dx'|^2dx$$ $$\leq\int_{0}^{1}e^{(\lambda)^2}|\int_{0}^{x}g(x')dx'|^2dx$$ by [Cauchy-Schwartz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855855/inequality-releating-squared-absolute-value-of-an-integral-to-the-integral-of-th) $$\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^{\lambda^2}x(\int_{0}^{x}|g(x')|^2dx')dx$$ and integrand g(x') part is $\leq 1$ so we get $$\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^{\lambda^2}xdx$$ which is $=e^{\lambda^2}/2$

Comment: I made a mistake it should be $e^{\lambda(x-x')}\leq e^{|\lambda|}$ (because $x\leq 1$) and it goes outside the integral as $e^{2|\lambda|}$ not as $e^{\lambda^2}$