# Vector norm of integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, vector-analysis, integral-inequality

On the Wikipedia page for the mean value theorem there is this Lemma (Lemma 2 under [Mean value theorem for vector-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions)) that says:
Let $v:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$, then we have that
$$ \left\Vert\int_a^b v(t)\,dt\right\Vert\leq\int_a^b\Vert v(t)\Vert dt. $$
I found a paper that uses/states the following similar result
$$ \left\Vert\int_0^1 v(t)\,dt\right\Vert^2\leq\int_0^1\Vert v(t)\Vert^2 dt. $$
I can follow the proof from Wikipedia, but I'm not sure how to proof the 'squared' version above. I guess the fact the integral is taken from 0 to 1 is important. I did find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855855/inequality-releating-squared-absolute-value-of-an-integral-to-the-integral-of-th) which asks a similar question, but it seems rely on it being a scalar function there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squaring the first inequality gives
$$
\left\Vert\int_0^1 v(t)\,dt\right\Vert^2\leq\left(\int_0^1\Vert v(t)\Vert \, dt \right)^2 \, .
$$
Now apply [Inequality releating squared absolute value of an integral to the integral of the squared absolute values of the integrand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855855/inequality-releating-squared-absolute-value-of-an-integral-to-the-integral-of-th) to the scalar-valued function $f(t) = \Vert v(t)\Vert$ to conclude that the right-hand side is
$$
 \le \int_0^1\Vert v(t)\Vert^2 \, dt \,  .
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\{e_1, \dots, e_m\}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^m$ and $v : t \mapsto v_1(t) e_1 + \dots + v_m(t) e_m$ **then by definition of the vector integral**

$$\int_0^1 v(t) \ dt = \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\int_0^1 v_i(t) \ dt \right) e_i$$ and therefore if $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ stands for the Euclidean norm

$$\left\Vert \int_0^1 v(t) \ dt \right\Vert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\int_0^1 v_i(t) \ dt \right)^2 \le \int_0^1 \left(\sum_{i=1}^m v_i^2(t) \right) \ dt = \int_0^1 \Vert v(t) \Vert^2 \ dt$$

Comment: What's the name of the inequality used in proof?

Comment: I believe they used Jensen's Inequality to pull the square into the integral, and then the fact that sum of the integral is the integral of the sum to put summation inside.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\left(||\int_0^1v(t)dt||\right)^2\leq\left(\int_0^1||v(t)||dt\right)^2$$
by the first result and the monotonicity of $x\mapsto x^2$ on $[0,\infty)$. If $t\mapsto||v(t)||$ is summable then by the convexity of $x\mapsto x^2$ and [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) it follows
$$\left(\int_0^1||v(t)||dt\right)^2\leq\int_0^1||v(t)||^2dt$$
and thus the desired result.